# Square root of normal positive operators over real Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

A bounded linear operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is called a positive operator if $\langle Ax, x\rangle \geq 0$ for all  $x$ in $H$. It is known that, if $A$ is a positive operator on a Hilbert space  $H$ over the complex field $\mathbb{C}$, then $A$ has unique positive square root.

My question is the following: 
Does a normal positive operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space over the real field $\mathbb{R}$ ha*ve* a normal positive square root? If it exists, is it unique?

Comment: Your definition of "positive operator" is in some sense not the right one in a real Hilbert space, since it doesn't imply self-adjointness.  Are you sure it is the definition you want to work with?

Comment: @NateEldredge, Thank you for the reply. Yes, I would like to work with this definition. I am aware of the result that, self adjoint positive operators on the real Hilbert spaces have unique square roots. Please let me know some references related to this problem.

Comment: Do you know whether this is true in finite dimensions?

Comment: @NateEldredge I do not know for the answer for the finite dimensional case.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to both questions is **yes**.

First a word about terminology: as pointed out by Nate Eldredge and Nik Weaver in the comments, there are two notions of positivity at play here. To avoid any confusion, let us say that an operator $T$ on a real Hilbert space $\mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}}$ is:

- *quasi-positive* if $\langle Tx,x\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}}$;
- *positive semidefinite* if it is quasi-positive and self-adjoint.

In order to answer the question, we must pass to the complexification of $\mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}}$.

### The complexification.

A *complex conjugation* on a complex vector space $V$ is a conjugate linear map $f : V \to V$ which is equal to its own inverse:

- For all $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{C}$ and all $x,y\in V$ we have $f(\lambda x + \mu y) = \overline\lambda f(x) + \overline\mu f(y)$.
- For all $x\in V$ we have $f(f(x)) = x$.

The conjugation is usually written $\bar{\ }\, : V \to V$ instead of $f$, and the conjugate of an element $x\in V$ is written $\overline x$. We say an element $x \in V$ is *real* if $\overline x = x$ holds. The set of all real elements forms a real subspace of $V$, denoted by $\text{Re}(V)$. This is clearly not a complex subspace. In fact, every $x \in V$ can be written uniquely as $x = a + ib$ with $a,b\in\text{Re}(V)$.

If $\mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}}$ is a real Hilbert space, then it has a *complexification*, a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}}$ together with a complex conjugation $\bar{\ }\, : \mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}} \to \mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}}$ such that

- The conjugation satisfies any (and therefore all) of the following equivalent properties:

  - For all $x,y\in\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}}$ we have $\langle \overline x,\overline y\rangle = \overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$.
  - For all $x,y\in\text{Re}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$ we have $\langle x,y\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$.
  - For all $a,b\in\text{Re}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$ we have $\lVert a + ib\rVert^2 = \lVert a\rVert^2 + \lVert b\rVert^2$.
  - For all $x\in\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}}$ we have $\lVert \overline x\rVert = \lVert x\rVert$.
- The real subspace $\text{Re}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$ is Hilbert space isomorphic to $\mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}}$.

With these properties, the complexification is uniquely defined (up to isomorphism). Every operator $T \in B_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}})$ extends uniquely to an operator in $B_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$, and this extension gives us a unital, isometric (real) $*$-homomorphism
$$ \phi : B_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}}) \to B_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}}). $$
We get an induced complex conjugation $\bar{\ }\,$ on $B_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$, which maps an operator $S \in B_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$ to the operator $x \mapsto \overline{S\,\overline x}$. The image of the above homomorphism $\phi$ is precisely the real subspace consisting of all operators which are real with respect to the induced conjugation on $B_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$.

For $S,T \in B_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$ we have $\overline{ST} = \overline S\,\overline T$. The identity $1$ is real, so we find that $S$ is invertible if and only if $\overline S$ is inverible, in which case we have $\overline{S}^{\,-1} = \overline{S^{-1}}$. From this it follows that $\sigma(\overline S) = \overline{\sigma(S)}$ holds for any $S\in B_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$. In particular, the spectrum of a real element is a self-adjoint subset of $\mathbb{C}$. (However it need not be real – a real square matrix can have complex eigenvalues!)

### Quasi-positive normal operators.

Note that an operator $T \in B_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}})$ is quasi-positive if and only if its self-adjoint part $\tfrac{1}{2}(T + T^*)$ is positive semidefinite. This is because we have $\langle Tx,x\rangle = \langle x,T^*x\rangle = \langle T^*x,x\rangle$, hence
$$ \langle Tx,x\rangle = \langle T^*x,x\rangle = \left\langle \tfrac{1}{2}(T + T^*)x,x\right\rangle. $$
It follows that a normal operator $T \in B_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}})$ is quasi-positive if and only if its complex spectrum $\sigma_{\mathbb{C}}(T) := \sigma(\phi(T))$ is contained in the closed right half plane $\{\text{Re}(z) \geq 0\}$. (Use the Gelfand representation of the commutative $C^*$-subalgebra $C^*(\phi(T)) \subseteq B_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$ generated by $\phi(T)$.) This allows us to define quasi-positivity for *complex* normal operators: we say that a normal operator $S \in B_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$ is *quasi-positive* if and only if $\sigma(S)$ is contained in the closed right half plane $\{\text{Re}(z) \geq 0\}$. The principal branch of the complex square root defines a continuous function from the closed right half plane to itself, so we may use the Gelfand representation of $C^*(S)$ to obtain a quasi-positive normal square root $R$ of any quasi-positive normal operator $S$. Now, if $R'$ is any quasi-positive normal square root of $S$, then we may use the Gelfand representation of $C^*(R')$ to prove that $R = R'$ must hold. (We have $S \in C^*(R')$, hence $R \in C^*(S) \subseteq C^*(R')$.) This shows that quasi-positive normal square roots are necessarily unique.

Next, let $S \in B_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{C}})$ be quasi-positive, normal, and such that $\sigma(S)$ is self-adjoint. Now:

- For a complex polynomial $p$ in $\lambda$ and $\overline\lambda$, we define $\overline p$ to be the coefficient-wise complex conjugate of $p$, without interchanging the variables. Then we have $\overline p\big(\overline\lambda\big) = \overline{p(\lambda)}$.
- The principal branch ${\scriptstyle\surd} : \{\text{Re}(z) \geq 0\} \to \{\text{Re}(z) \geq 0\}$ of the complex square root satisfies a similar, yet slightly different property: ${\scriptstyle\surd}\big(\overline{\lambda}\big) = \overline{{\scriptstyle\surd}(\lambda)}$.

Hence, if $\{p_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of complex polynomials in $\lambda$ and $\overline\lambda$ converging to ${\scriptstyle\surd}$ uniformly on $\sigma(S)$, then we have
$$ \left|{\scriptstyle\surd}(\lambda) - \overline{p_n}(\lambda)\right| \: = \: \left|\overline{{\scriptstyle\surd}\big(\overline\lambda\big)} - \overline{p_n\big(\overline\lambda\big)}\right| \: = \: \left|{\scriptstyle\surd}\big(\overline\lambda\big) - p_n\big(\overline\lambda\big)\right|, $$
so it follows that the sequence $\{\overline{p_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ also converges to ${\scriptstyle\surd}$ uniformly on $\sigma(S)$. Consequently, the sequence $\{\tfrac{1}{2}(p_n + \overline{p_n})\}_{n=1}^\infty$ also converges to ${\scriptstyle\surd}$ uniformly on $\sigma(S)$. This is a sequence of *real* polynomials in $\lambda$ and $\overline\lambda$, so now we see that the unique quasi-positive normal square root of $S$ lies in the closed *real* subalgebra generated by $S$ and $S^*$. From this it follows that a real quasi-positive normal operator has a (unique) real quasi-positive normal square root.

In fact, the argument can be extended to show that every normal operator $T \in B_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}})$ satisfying $\sigma(T) \cap \mathbb{R}_{<0} = \varnothing$ has a unique quasi-positive normal square root in $B_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathcal H_{\mathbb{R}})$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: where do we use the fact that $T$ is normal? Do existence and uniqueness of positive square root still hold if we drop that condition? Thanks!

Comment: @JianingSong The assumption is definitely needed — some square matrices do not have a square root at all, let alone a quasi-positive one (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65227/under-what-conditions-does-a-matrix-a-have-a-square-root)). The assumption is used when we apply continuous functional calculus to approximate ${\scriptstyle\surd}$ by polynomials in $\lambda$ and $\overline\lambda$ — this is only defined when $S$ and $S^*$ commute (i.e. $S$ is normal).

Comment: Here, [continuous functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus) refers to the common technique of applying a continuous function $f : \sigma(S) \to \mathbb{C}$ to a normal operator $S$, by approximating $f$ by polynomials in $z$ and $\overline{z}$ that converge to $f$ uniformly on $\sigma(S)$. This can only be done if $S$ and $S^*$ commute — otherwise, one can only meaningfully apply polynomials in either $z$ or $\overline{z}$, not both.

Comment: @JianingSong Come to think of it, it is still possible to obtain a square root of certain non-normal operators by using the [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus) instead of the continuous one. This requires ${\scriptstyle\surd}$ to be holomorphic in an open neighbourhood $U$ of $\sigma(S)$, so this does not work for all operators (indeed, not all operators have a square root). In particular, for this approach to work, we must have $0 \notin \sigma(S)$ (that is, $S$ must be invertible).

Comment: In this setting, it might even be possible to get a real (instead of complex) square root of the operator by working with a power series expansion of ${\scriptstyle\surd}$ on $U$ with only real coefficients. For instance, if $\sigma(S) \subseteq \{\text{Re}(z) > 0\}$, then a series expansion of ${\scriptstyle\surd}$ like the one given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/884839) shows that $S$ has a real square root.

Comment: I don't see how one would ensure that the obtained square root is quasi-positive. We get $\sigma(S^{1/2}) \subseteq \{\text{Re}(z) \geq 0\}$, but for non-normal operators this doesn't necessarily imply $\langle S^{1/2}x,x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x$. Maybe a more careful analysis, using the series expansion of ${\scriptstyle\surd}$, can somehow show that $S^{1/2}$ is also quasi-positive? I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we have a spectral theorem for operators on real Hilbert spaces. The multiplication operator version says that there is a Hilbert space isomorphism between $H$ and some real $L^2$ space which turns $A$ into multiplication by some function. If $A$ is positive, multiplication by the square root of the function is a positive square root of $A$. Working in the multiplication operator picture, it's easy to see that for any positive operator $B$ the operator $B^2$ has the same spectral subspaces, from which it easily follows that positive square roots are unique.

Comment: I don't think it's that easy.  With $H = \mathbb{R}^2$, the operator $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is normal and positive by this definition, but it isn't self-adjoint.  It's not diagonalizable over the reals, so no isomorphism of real Hilbert spaces can make it into a multiplication operator.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that his definition of "positive" was nonstandard!

Comment: Incidentally, though, my operator $A$ does have a "positive" square root, namely $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (A+I)$.  (This is "positive" since $A+I$ is the sum of two "positive" operators.)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. Indeed, it is the unique "positive" square root.